# How can I detect devices on my local network from a Linux computer?

Tags: networking

> After many researching, I have concluded that this question must be
>   plataform-dependent, so I am asking here the Unix/Linux one.

The best method I know until now to detect **devices connected** to my LAN (wired o wireless) is a neat program for Android named [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=es) .

Detecting devices on a LAN is not a easy/straightforward task, as long as some devices do not ask to ping, some others have open ports but even [nMap](https://nmap.org/) does not detect both the device nor the open port, and so on.

Even *specific tools* that perform ping sweeps or ARP reading use to **miss devices**. For example: the above referred Fing does sometimes require a few refreshings until fully detecting everything (routers, managed switchs, NAS... etc) on a LAN.

What is the **proper method, tool or procedure** to perform (to obtain the more exhaustive results) this search from a **Linux** computer?

- Open Source options preferred. Free encouraged. Payment alternatives only as last resource.

Comment: you may look here https://alternativeto.net/software/fing/?platform=linux  I hope it can help you to find a good tool. However since you know an android tool yhat feet your needs, just use it from an android JDK or VM it should be a solution.

Answer (score 4):

`netdiscover` uses active and passive scanning to detect hosts on the local network. It crafts ARP requests; probing for each possible address. After this (quick) scan is completed, it can continue running passively to detect hosts when they send ARP packets. The interface is very barebones and only shows discovered addresses, ARP count, and OUI manufacturer.

You can also use the `-sn` option of `nmap` to perform a host discovery scan. This scan has different behavior depending what user you run it as, and whether you are scanning a local network or not. It will list the hosts that are determined to be online.